# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error can't see where to make variable accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting the following error when I create a new object from my form: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: feature_ids`. In my models I have the following:

```
class Outboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :make, :model, :price, :features
  has_many :features, :through => :Outboardfeature
  has_many :Outboardfeature
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :outboards, :through => :Outboardfeature
  has_many :Outboardfeature
end

class Outboardfeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :feature_id, :outboard_id
  belongs_to :feature, :class_name => "Feature", :foreign_key => "feature_id"
  belongs_to :outboard, :class_name => "Outboard", :foreign_key => "outboard_id"
end
```

I can't see where to make the feature_ids accessible from the error as in my Outboard model I have made features accessible.

Comment: The form to which the controller belongs to?

Comment: Have you tried `attr_accessible :make, :model, :price, :feature_ids` ?

Comment: Why to break conventions? Why's there `has_many :Outboardfeature` instead of `has_many :outboard_features`? And why do you specify `class_name` and `foregin_key` in your `belongs_to` when they can be inferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `:feature_ids` to the Outboard Models `attr_accessible`.